# how can I delete the elements of array after read it in C++?

Tags: c++

```
Array<Personne> personnes;  
while (in) {
    Personne newPersonne;
    in >> newPersonne;
    if (in.eof()) break;
    personnes.add(newPersonne);
    if (personnes.size() > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < personnes.size() - 1; ++i) 
            for (int j = i + 1; j < personnes.size(); ++j) {
                string typeRelation = personnes[i].getTypeRelation(personnes[j]);
                if (typeRelation != "")
                    cout << personnes[i].getNom() << " and " << personnes[j].getNom() << " are " << typeRelation << endl;
                if (j ==  personnes.size() -1){
                    personnes.delete(i); //doesn't work very well, want to delete the first element when finishing the copmarison withe the other elements.

                }    
            }
    }
}
```

I want to delete the first elements of the Array when the second loop reaches its end.

Comment: There appear to be some basic things you are missing regarding object lifetime and memory allocation. I would recommend reading up on these things.

Comment: What is `Array`? The only standard array template I know `std::array` (first letter is lower-cased).  Also, `delete` is a reseved keyword which shouldn't appear at this context.

Comment: Look at the definition of your `Array` template, it will probably have a "remove" or "erase" (or similar) method. It won't be called "delete" as this is a reserved keyword. Without knowing how `Array` is defined no one will be able to give you any more definite help.

Comment: this is my template arrat code   { ' emplate <class T>
void Tableau<T>::delete(int index)
{
    assert(index < nbElements && index >= 0);

    for(int i = index; i < nbElements; i++)
        elements[i] = elements[i+1];
    nbElements--;
}'

Comment: Where did `Tableau` come from? The template in your question is called `Array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of killers in the Tableau::delete method:

The function will not compile because of the use of the `delete` keyword as the function's name

`elements[index+1]` will allow reading `elements[nbElements]` Which may or may not be out of the array's bounds, but is certainly one more than intended.

Try instead:

```
template <class T> 
void Tableau<T>::remove(size_t index) // size_t is unsigned and prevents input of 
                                      // negative numbers. One less test required.
                                      // nbElements should also be made unsigned to match
                                      // function name changed to something legal.
{   
    assert(index < nbElements); // this also ensures nbElements is > 1 
                                // so nbElements-- will not go out of bounds
    nbElements--; // moved above the loop because the index+1 will grab the last element
    for( ; index < nbElements; index++) // no need to have an i. Index already does this
    {
        elements[index] = elements[index+1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky with arrays, removing the first item requires you to move everything after it left one (so the 2nd item becomes the 1st item).  you can use a loop for this if you want but I think the better option would be to use a different data structure like a Deque http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/

Comment: How can you know that without knowing what the `Array` class template is?

Comment: what do you mean by "know that"?  I'm guessing you're asking how I know that's how the array works?  If so, then that's how all arrays work it doesn't matter what the class template is.  If you just delete the first item in the array all you have is a nullptr as the first item, so you didn't accomplish removing the item from the array as the 2nd item is still the 2nd item and not the 1st item.

Comment: His point is that Array could be wrapping an array, but it could also front a linked list, or something even more gonzo like a binary tree. OP has since added a comment and is doing exactly what you suggest, but is tripping over what is likely the real villain: using the delete keyword as a function name.

Comment: `template <class T>
void Tableau<T>::delete(int index)
{
    assert(index < nbElements && index >= 0);

    for(int i = index; i < nbElements; i++)
        elements[i] = elements[i+1];
    nbElements--;
}`  _this is my template class for delete .

Comment: user4581301 is correct, 'delete' is a reserved keyword and is most likely causing your problems.  Rename it to 'remove' or 'erase'.  Also elements[i+1] might cause a problem when you reach the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < personnes.size() - 1; ++i)
// other file

template <class T>
void Tableau<T>::delete (int index) 
{
    assert(index < nbElements && index >= 0);
    for(int i = index; i < nbElements; i++) elements[i] = elements[i+1];
    nbElements--;
}
```

if size() is calculated with nbElements, then choose between :

```
for (int i (index); i < personnes.size();)
```

and changing the way you remove empty cases of your Array. (without changing the position of the next person tested)

because i believe you jump 1 person out of two :
you check person i then you replace person i + 1 to person i then you check person i+1 (which is actually person i+2)